# do stdint.h supported in opencl?

Tags: opencl

I want to use uint8_t datatype in opencl. I have just declared to check if it is supported or not but it gives some error regarding stdint.h. The C file while running compiles the .cl code and gets this error

`Compilation started
      In file included from 1:1:
      In file included from /usr/include/stdint.h:25:
      In file included from /usr/include/features.h:399:
      /usr/include/gnu/stubs.h:7:11: fatal error: 'gnu/stubs-32.h' file not found
Compilation failed`

Is it some machine error or stdint.h is not supported in openCL? How can I make it working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should avoid including any system headers from your OpenCL kernels.

Just use `uchar` instead. You can `typedef uchar uint8_t;` if you need to.